# Can no longer bake shadows to my plane's texture, coming out white

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, baking, shadows

I'm pretty new to blender and working on my first little project. I've been baking shadows to 1024p textures on my floor plane, and all was working correctly. But now after booting up the program today baking just yields white results and I have no clue why.

It's acting as if there aren't any shadows and it's just completely white: 
[image]

Where in rendered mode, you can see otherwise.

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Oh and here's the .blend if necessary(ignore my noob habits if I have any) https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjexrehd68re8rb/Table.blend?dl=0

Comment: Blender doesnt save the Bake maps internally, you have to save them to your Harddisk, otherwise if you restart Blender they are gone.